# How to open a new WPF user control in a WPF user control?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to open another user control in a user control but if gives me this error: "System.InvalidOperationException"
Can someone help me fix this erroer?

```
private void BtnBrdjGezond_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl usc = null;
        usc = new UserControlHome();
        this.AddChild(usc);
    }
```

Comment: Do not use AddChild. Add the control to the Children collection of a Panel in the parent control.

Comment: You mean like this: this.Controls.add(usercontrol);

Comment: and where is it asked before because I can't find it...

Comment: No, there should be a Panel, e.g. a Grid, where you can call `grid.Children.Add(usc)`